# Changing deselected highlight color in Attribute Editor window

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, editing

Does anyone know if you can change the highlighted color or deselected color in the Attribute Editor window? My eyes are about to bleed from the strain. Here's what I'm talking about:

[image]

This light gray color after I click off of it is nearly invisible to my eyes. I'm running ArcMap 10.2.1

Comment: You may find this is a Windows setting rather than an ArcGIS Desktop setting

Comment: I wasn't sure, but I'm going to try that in the morning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will provide a solution assuming that you are using Windows 10. Right-click on your `Decktop -> Personalization -> Select Color`

[image]

Then scroll down until you see `High Contrast Setiings`

[image]

Select from the drop down menu the color you want. Here I chose `High Contrast White`.

[image]

Then I customized the `Button Text` to a different color, and I save it a new a theme, as you can see below:

[image]

Now the attribute table in ArcGIS of deselected item highlighted in Pink:

[image]

But, as you can see everything becomes pink. Thus, you need to test/choose different colors to get the one you like.

Comment: My machine runs Windows 7 but same steps applied. I just needed to change my 3D objects color. My eyes thanks you.